# Python generalized sql database connector

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Currently, to connect to various database I use the following:

```
# MySQL
try:
    conn = pymssql.connect(host=self.host, port=self.port, user=self.user, password=self.password, database=self.database)
except Exception as e:
    raise ConnectionError("MsSQL Error: %s" % e)

# Oracle
try:
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(self.host, self.port, self.database)
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(self.user, self.password, dsn_tns)
except Exception as e:
    raise ConnectionError("Oracle Error: %s" % e)

# PostgreSQL
    try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host=self.host, port=self.port, user=self.user, password=self.password, database=self.database)
except Exception as e:
    raise ConnectionError("PostgreSQL Error: %s" % e)

# MsSQL
try:
    conn = pymssql.connect(host=self.host, port=self.port, user=self.user, password=self.password, database=self.database)
except Exception as e:
    raise ConnectionError("MsSQL Error: %s" % e)
```

Is there a way in python to connect to all using the same `connector`? For example, something like:

```
odbc.connect(host, port, user, password, database, engine="MYSQL")
```

Comment: I think that SQLAlchemy will do what you're looking to do. The engines documentation provides examples on using the `create_engine` method to establish connections using postgres, oracle, mysql, sql server check it out at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html.

Comment: @RobertH what's better, sqlalchemy or pyodbc?

Comment: @RobertH also -- wouldn't you still need to install all the individualized drivers? For example the connection string is: `mysql+pymysql://`

Comment: To be honest I haven't used either, I am aware of SQL Alchemy as I investigated its use previously, pyodbc I haven't looked into at all. You will need to provide the drivers for each of the databases you wish to support - I don't see how you would get around that regardless of the framework used. For the open source databases you list I would imagine you could place those within the project without much issue, but MS and Oracle likely have redistribution clauses you may need to review. I'm certainly not an expert here though so I may be off on this

Comment: Create a function to connect to each DBMS, and another function that takes the "engine" argument and redirects to the appropriate DBMS-specific function.

Comment: @rd_nielsen that's what I'm currently doing (though not shown above). Using a factory method to instantiate each connection.